# Getting grouped data from database and process further in java

Tags: java, database, performance, group-by

I have a table , say `A` ; now in `A` i have attribute `ID` as `string` and `Time` as `DateTime`.

Now the condition is that different entries to the table can have same `ID` and they have to be clubbed together and further do some refinement on it.

I am using java, I write the SQL query that

```
Select * from A group by ID;
```

Now i get this data in a huge list in java. Now what i do is

```
Set_ID=NULL;
for(each element in List)
{
  if(Set_ID equals elements `ID` from table)
    Add the element to the same list
  else
    Create new List and add element to the list. Change Set_ID to current `ID`
}
```

This way i get all the Entries with same Id in different lists and i can process further. 
But is this the efficient way to this; comparing strings for each element.

Any change i can make, to make it better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading all the data into a list & then processing it into sub lists, I'd process them directly into sub lists as you pull them from the database